# Gap between window controls and client area

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, layout, window

How do I remove the gap highlighted from my window?

[image]

I'm extending the glass into the client area, but there is a gap underneath the miminize, maximize/restore and close buttons.

Comment: @Daniel A. White, you mean the section with a red gradient?

Comment: @Hasan: He wants the title bar to me smaller so that the bottom of the title bar is at the bottom of the buttons.

Comment: I don't see any glass anywhere at all... What function are you calling to extend the glass into the client area? Can you show us some code? How did that area turn red? Do you have some custom painting code at work? That's not anywhere near normal.

Comment: I'm fine with getting the glass. I'm refering to the gap directly below the buttons like @TomWij said.

Comment: @Daniel: wasn't me, but I'll bet some folks were looking for the code you've used.

Comment: I downvoted this. I've gotten this effect to work numerous times, and I really would love to try to help you. But I can't. There's nowhere near enough information here to go on. You don't tell us what function you're calling to extend the frame (`DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` is the right one), you don't show us the code you're using, you don't tell us why that area turned red, etc. etc. I asked about this in my last comment. I was planning to remove the downvote once you updated the question and @replied to me. Unfortunately, that never happened. I'm surprised you think this is answerable.

Answer (score 0):

[Use Interop calls to extend the frame into the client area](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/257101c0-07d9-4ae8-843e-9706616e3afc).

Alternatively, you could [design your own custom WPF window](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/custom_wpf_windows.htm) and play with the transparency.